# With python logging module, is there a way to indicate how many times a program has been run?

Tags: python, logging

I was wondering if there was a way to id everytime an app has started with the python logging module, like this:

```
########
New instance started at 01/07/21
Instance ID: 0x23B5D
########
```

I wanted to do this so I could reference a particular instance when debugging an app. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that code i have written

```py
from logging import getLogger, FileHandler, INFO
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime


class MyFileHandler(FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, *args):
        super().__init__(filename, *args)
        self.stream.write(
            "########\n"
            "New instance started at {}\n"
            "Instance ID: {}\n"
            "########\n".format(datetime.now(), hex(randint(0, int(3e10))).upper()),
        )


logger = getLogger("main")
logger.addHandler(MyFileHandler("main.log"))
logger.setLevel(INFO)
```

and every time you log to a file, for example

```py
logger.info("Hello World!")
logger.error("An error has been occurred!")
```

it will log it into the file, in addition, at the beginning of each execution of the program it will log something like:

```
########
New instance started at 2021-07-01 09:55:04.647079
Instance ID: 0X2E02B30FA
########
```

as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following to your code

to get the time of execution

```
from time import strftime

log_date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ")
    

with open("log.txt", "a") as f2:
    f2.write("Program executed at: " + log_date_time + "\n")
```

everytime you execute your python program the log.txt will store the time like this

[image]